# Dictionary have key with multiple values of list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Dictionary have one key with multiple values in a list of list
ex:-

```
dict1 = {'SN': [['023061', '023069'], '023071'],'File_size': [[1.1, 1.86], 1.1]}
```

o/p:-

```
dict1 = {'SN': ['023061', '023069', '023071'],'File_size': [1.1, 1.86, 1.1]}
```

Please give a solution as much as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been easier if the list contained only lists, but here the list also contains an integer here. My code over here I suppose will work, but is not the most effective way to do your task :

```py
for key in dict1:
    a = dict1[key]
    s = []
    for row in a:
        if type(row) == type([]):
            for item in row:
                s += [item]
        else:
            s += [row]
    dict1[key] = s
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to recursively flatten a list(handles deeper uneven nested lists):

```
def flatten(lst):
    result = []

    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for sub in flatten(item):
                result.append(sub)
        else:
            result.append(item)

    return result
```

Then create a new dictionary and call `flatten()` on the values:

```
dict1 = {'SN': [['023061', '023069'], '023071'],'File_size': [[1.1, 1.86], 1.1]}

result = {k: flatten(v) for k, v in dict1.items()}

print(result)
# {'SN': ['023061', '023069', '023071'], 'File_size': [1.1, 1.86, 1.1]}
```

You could also use `yield` here as well:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

result = {k: list(flatten(v)) for k, v in dict1.items()}

print(result)
# {'SN': ['023061', '023069', '023071'], 'File_size': [1.1, 1.86, 1.1]}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def single_list(value):
    final=[]
    for x in value:
        if isinstance(x,list)==False:
               x=[x]
        final.extend(x)
    return final
dic1 = {key:single_list(value) for key,value in dic1.items() }
```

Explanation: using dictionary comprehension, we will apply single_list() to values corresponding each key.On looping over these values, we will check if each element of 'value' is list or not. If not, convert it to list and extend to 'final'